# How to remove custom Office meeting template?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, calendar, templates

A long time ago I set up a custom meeting template in Outlook Calendar that would include some basic information, a link to a web meeting tool, and some default agenda. When I double-click in my Outlook calendar, the meeting invite includes this information. I can also click on this button directly from the Ribbon:

[image]

After we switched to Teams and O365 this is no longer necessary, but I can't seem to remove this. I've checked a bunch of articles that say I need to remove them from `%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates` but there are no custom templates there. What I've done so far:

- Verified no templates are stored in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office`
- Verified no templates are stored in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`
- Verified no templates are stored in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office`
- Verified no templates are stored in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook`
- Removed all office template files under `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

  - Side note here that when I start up Outlook a file called `NormalEmail.dotm` is automatically created here.
- Verified no templates are stored in `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates`
- Removed all office template files under `C:\Users\MyUser\My Documents\Custom Office Templates`
- Restarted the computer after removing the templates in the above folders

I've also seen that you can specify a Personal template folder in some articles but that is only available under `File > Options > Save` and this setting doesn't exist in Outlook for me, only for Word, Excel, and Powerpoint.

Is there anyone who knows how I can get rid of this custom outlook calendar template?

**EDIT:** I also ran `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\MyUser" -Recurse -Force | Where-Object{$_.Name -like "*.oft"}` and that returned nothing.

**EDIT2:** If I right-click my Calendar and go to `Properties`, I have a dropdown list called `When posting to this folder, use:` and from there I can select `IPM.Appointment` and the `RemoteSession` (that I want to remove).

[image]

If I change to `IPM.Appointment` the default now is a standard appointment, but it irks me that the `RemoteSession` object is still stored somewhere and I can't remove it... `Clear offline files` doesn't help, and the `Forms...` section shows my personal forms folder as empty.

Comment: Have you tried to simply right-clicking on it and seeing if you can delete it that way?

Comment: I have, and that gives me 5 options: Add to Quick Access Toolbar, Hide Quick Access Toolbar, Customize Ribbon, Collapse Ribbon, and Use Simplified Ribbon. Customizing the ribbon gives me the option to reset the tab which does nothing to the RemoteSession object. Going into a meeting invite and then from there selecting File > Options gives me the same as if done through Outlook without having opened anything.

Comment: Well, at least you tried.

Comment: Added some more troubleshooting steps, I found a way to hide it but not remove it...

Comment: How did you set up the custom meeting template in Outlook Calendar ?

Comment: Absolutely no memory of how I did that, too long time ago.

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to find the original method creating the template to better delete it.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that out myself, this post is asking if somebody knows how to do that.